# Error with the Copy constructor and equality operator

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, vector, implementation

I am making my own implementation of the class "vector" with templates as practise. Everything seems to be working except the Copy constructor and the overloaded = operator. I am not sure where exactly the problem is. I will post the entire source code below:(Also I am not sure if I have any leaks)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename TT1>
class Vector{
private:
    int size;
    TT1* ptr;
public:
    Vector();
    ~Vector();
    Vector(int size);
    Vector(const Vector& a);
    Vector<TT1>& operator=(const Vector& a);
    void set(int position, TT1 data);
    TT1 get(int position);
    int get_size();
};

//------Default Constructor------
template <typename TT1>
Vector<TT1> :: Vector()
{
    size = 0;
    ptr = NULL;
}

//-------Copy Constructor-------
template <typename TT1>
Vector<TT1> :: Vector(const Vector<TT1>& a)
{
    if(a.ptr != NULL)
    {
        this->size = a.size;
        delete[] ptr;
        ptr = new TT1[size];
        for ( int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
                this->ptr[i] = a.ptr[i];
    }
}

//------Destructor-------
template <typename TT1>
Vector<TT1> :: ~Vector()
{
    delete[] ptr;
}

//-----Overloaded = operator----
template <typename TT1>
Vector<TT1>& Vector<TT1> :: operator=(const Vector<TT1>& a)
{
    if(this != &a)
    {
        this->size = a.size;
        delete[] this->ptr;
        this->ptr = new TT1[a.size];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
                this->ptr[i] = a.ptr[i];
        return *this;
    }
}
//----Constructor with size---
template<typename TT1>
Vector<TT1> :: Vector(int size)
{
    this->size = size;
    ptr = new TT1[size];
}

//---- Set data @ Poisition----
template<typename TT1>
void Vector<TT1> :: set(int position, TT1 data)
{
    *(ptr+ position) = data;
}

//----Get data From position----
template<typename TT1>
TT1 Vector<TT1> :: get(int position)
{
    return *(ptr + position);
}

//-----Get size----
template<typename TT1>
int Vector<TT1> :: get_size()
{
    return size;
}

void foo(Vector<string> a)
{

}

int main()
{
    Vector<string> a(3);
    a.set(0, "asd");
    a.set(2, "hjk");
    a.set(1, "34645!");
    for(int i = 0; i < a.get_size(); i++)
    {
        cout << a.get(i) << endl;
    }
    Vector<string> b = a;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.get_size(); i++)
    {
        cout << b.get(i) << endl;
    }
    foo(a);

    return 0;
}
```

And now the parts where the mistakes are:

```
template <typename TT1>
Vector<TT1> :: Vector(const Vector<TT1>& a)
{
    if(a.ptr != NULL)
    {
        this->size = a.size;
        delete[] ptr;
        ptr = new TT1[size];
        for ( int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
                this->ptr[i] = a.ptr[i];
    }
}
```

And finally here:

```
//-----Overloaded = operator----
template <typename TT1>
Vector<TT1>& Vector<TT1> :: operator=(const Vector<TT1>& a)
{
    if(this != &a)
    {
        this->size = a.size;
        delete[] this->ptr;
        this->ptr = new TT1[a.size];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
                this->ptr[i] = a.ptr[i];
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: +1 For very clearly written question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You delete a pointer that was never allocated:

```
//-------Copy Constructor-------
template <typename TT1>
Vector<TT1> :: Vector(const Vector<TT1>& a)
{
    std::cout << "Vector(const Vector<TT1>& a), " << a.size << std::endl;
    if(a.ptr != NULL)
    {
        this->size = a.size;
        delete[] ptr;  //<-------------- no corresponding new
        ptr = new TT1[size];
        for ( int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
                this->ptr[i] = a.ptr[i];
    }
}
```

Just comment that out, and [it works fine](http://ideone.com/NSCNoV#view_edit_box).

**Edit**: Per Mike Seymour's observation, the members esp. `ptr` should be initialized:

```
Vector<TT1> :: Vector(const Vector<TT1>& a) : size(0), ptr(NULL)
{
...
}
```

In addition, although the compiler accepts it for constructor/operator= apparently, you will otherwise get an 'incomplete type' error if you write code of the form

```
Vector(const Vector& a);
Vector<TT1>& operator=(const Vector& a);
```

Rather, for consistency and good style imho include the template parameters:

```
Vector(const Vector<TT1>& a);
Vector<TT1>& operator=(const Vector<TT1>& a);
```

And similarly in the definitions.

Comment: This is just for the copy constructor, right? I should keep the delete in the overloaded '=' ?

Comment: It works fine... unless you copy an empty vector. Then the copy constructor leaves the members uninitialised, and the destructor is likely to explode.

Comment: @Bloodcount Yes, absolutely--but only if it's non-null.  You should have `if (this->ptr) delete[] this->ptr;` and `size` and `ptr` should be in an initializer list.  (The latter of these is good practice but not essential.)  I've updated the code sample accordingly.

Comment: I understand my error and it is unlikely that I will do it again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MikeSeymour Good call, I've accounted for that now in an edit.